# jQuery - ui-selectmenu-button blur()-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Okay - so for some reason or another, the jQuery UI Selectmenu-button messes with both focus() and blur()-events - they do not trigger. Is there a way to get these events to trigger, without having to use a function in the selectmenu()-assignment?

Reason I ask is that I have a overall function which is used for focus and blur-events on input, textarea and the like, which would be nice to also be able to use on selectmenu - but since it doesn't accept blur and focus, that makes it a bit more difficult.

Currently, I have the following code:

```
$('input,textarea,select').on('blur focus',function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        thisID = $this.attr('id'),
        thisType = $this.attr('type'),
        thisContent = $this.val(),
        thisForm = $this.parents('form').attr('id'),
        isRequired = $this.attr('required'),
        getMessage = '',
        elementPosition = $this.position(),
        elementWidth = $this.width(),
        elementHeight = $this.height(),
        checkmarkPosition = (elementPosition != undefined) ? elementPosition.left + (elementWidth-10) : '',
        topPosition = (elementPosition != undefined) ? Math.floor(elementPosition.top) : '';

        if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
            thisContent = $this.text();
        }

        if (event.type == 'blur') {
            if (isRequired == 'required' && (thisContent == '' || thisContent == 'Can\'t be empty')) {
                getMessage = 'requiredField';
            } else if (thisType == 'email') {
                if (validateEmail(thisContent) == false) {
                    getMessage = 'notValidEmail';
                } else {
                    getMessage = 'checkMark';
                }
            } else {
                getMessage = 'checkMark';
            }
        }

    if (getMessage != '' && getMessage != undefined) {
        $.post('/returnmessages.php', {getmessage:getMessage}, function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data),
            message = data.returnmessage,
            infoState = data.infostate;

            if (infoState != '' && infoState != undefined && thisType != 'submit') {
                if (infoState == 'success') {
                    $this.addClass(infoState).after('<span style="position: absolute; left: '+(checkmarkPosition)+'px; top: '+(topPosition+10)+'px;" class="fa fa-check"></span>');
                } else if (infoState == 'error' && (thisContent == '' || thisContent == undefined)) {
                    $this.addClass(infoState).prop('placeholder',message).next('span').remove();
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Which works fine for regular events on regular inputs, but not on selectmenu-elements. It is a function to return "ok" (checkmarks) and different error-messages and such in the elements themselves, so no need to attach error-messages in separate elements.

Anyone have an idea as to how to make this work?

Comment: I found that getting this to work using `ui-selectmenu` was too much hassle. Ended up redoing the CSS for the select-boxes (with custom buttons/arrows) and redoing the whole javascript-bit to fit the new HTML/CSS.a

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that select won't trigger your own function,you can use

```
$( "#selectionSomething" ).selectmenu({
    change: function(){
        $(this).trigger('blur')
    }
});
```

hope it's useful

Comment: It's useful, sort of - but it doesn't solve my problem. It works for when there is an actual change in the select - ie, someone picks an option. However, it does not work if no option is selected (ie it's "empty") - then it doesn't trigger, and there is no error shown to the user. Which means a success works, since that will trigger on the change, but a non-selection won't work.